# Matlab error using accelerator mode

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, simulink, mex

I´m building a complex model in Simulink which took 50 minutes to run completely. I would like to use the accelerator mode but, after install the right version of virtual studio and SDK (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96050-how-can-i-set-up-microsoft-visual-studio-2008-express-edition-for-use-with-matlab-7-7-r2008b-on-32) I still have this error:

```
  ### Building the Accelerator target for model: deg_final_FAST
### Generating code into build directory: H:\ale peticchia_March2016\Simulink\model\deg_final_FAST_accel_rtw
Warning: Function H:\ale peticchia_March2016\Simulink\model\input.m has
the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to
avoid a potential name conflict. 
### Invoking Target Language Compiler on deg_final_FAST.rtw
    tlc
    -r
    H:\ale peticchia_March2016\Simulink\model\deg_final_FAST_accel_rtw\deg_final_FAST.rtw
    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b\rtw\c\accel\accel.tlc
    -OH:\ale peticchia_March2016\Simulink\model\deg_final_FAST_accel_rtw
    -IC:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b\rtw\c\accel
    -IH:\ale peticchia_March2016\Simulink\model\deg_final_FAST_accel_rtw\tlc
    -IC:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b\rtw\c\tlc\mw
    -IC:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b\rtw\c\tlc\lib
    -IC:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b\rtw\c\tlc\blocks
    -IC:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b\rtw\c\tlc\fixpt
    -IC:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b\stateflow\c\tlc
    -aEnforceIntegerDowncast=1
    -aFoldNonRolledExpr=1
    -aInlineInvariantSignals=0
    -aInlineParameters=0
    -aLocalBlockOutputs=1
    -aRollThreshold=5
    -aForceBlockIOInitOptimize=0
    -aGenerateReport=0
    -aGenCodeOnly=0
    -aRTWVerbose=1
    -aIncludeHyperlinkInReport=0
    -aLaunchReport=0
    -aGenerateTraceInfo=0
    -aForceParamTrailComments=0
    -aGenerateComments=1
    -aIgnoreCustomStorageClasses=1
    -aIncHierarchyInIds=0
    -aMaxRTWIdLen=31
    -aShowEliminatedStatements=0
    -aIncDataTypeInIds=0
    -aInsertBlockDesc=0
    -aIgnoreTestpoints=0
    -aSimulinkBlockComments=1
    -aInlinedPrmAccess="Literals"
    -aTargetFcnLib="ansi_tfl_table_tmw.mat"
    -aIsPILTarget=0
    -aLogVarNameModifier="rt_"
    -aGenerateFullHeader=1
    -aGenerateTraceInfo=0
    -aIgnoreTestpoints=0
    -p10000


### Loading TLC function libraries

...
### Initial pass through model to cache user defined code
....
### Caching model source code
......................................................................
### Writing header file deg_final_FAST_acc_types.h
### Writing header file deg_final_FAST_acc.h
### Writing source file deg_final_FAST_acc.c
.
### Writing header file deg_final_FAST_acc_private.h
### Writing source file deg_final_FAST_acc_data.c
### Writing header file rt_nonfinite.h
### Writing source file rt_nonfinite.c
.
### Writing header file rtGetInf.h
### Writing source file rtGetInf.c
### Writing header file rtGetNaN.h
### Writing source file rtGetNaN.c
.
### TLC code generation complete.
Warning: Function H:\ale peticchia_March2016\Simulink\model\input.m has
the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to
avoid a potential name conflict. 
.
### Processing Template Makefile: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b\rtw\c\accel\accel_vcx64.tmf
### deg_final_FAST.mk which is generated from C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b\rtw\c\accel\accel_vcx64.tmf is up to date
### Building deg_final_FAST: .\deg_final_FAST.bat

H:\ale peticchia_March2016\Simulink\model\deg_final_FAST_accel_rtw>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\/../../VC/vcvarsall" AMD64  
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Beta2 x64 tools. 
WindowsSdkDir not found 

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility, Version 9.00.21022.08 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten. 

C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2008b\rtw\c\tools\vctools.mak(8) : fatal error U1052: Datei "ntwin32.mak" nicht gefunden 
Stop. 
The make command returned an error of 2 
'An_error_occurred_during_the_call_to_make' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file. 
### Real-Time Workshop build procedure for model: 'deg_final_FAST' aborted due to an error.
Warning: Function H:\ale peticchia_March2016\Simulink\model\input.m has
the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to
avoid a potential name conflict. 
Warning: Function H:\ale peticchia_March2016\Simulink\model\input.m has
the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to
avoid a potential name conflict. 
Warning: Function H:\ale peticchia_March2016\Simulink\model\input.m has
the same name as a MATLAB builtin. We suggest you rename the function to
avoid a potential name conflict. 
??? Error using ==> Degradation_model_matlab_fast at 27
Problem creating Accelerator MEX file for model 'deg_final_FAST'. Error
returned is:
 Error using ==> genMakefileAndBuild at 1079
Error(s) encountered while building model "deg_final_FAST".
```

Do you have suggestions?
Thanks for your help!

matlab R2008b
win7 64bit

Comment: I this the complete error message? I would expect some details in the next lines.

Comment: Please put the information into your question.

Comment: Yes is better ;) . I did it!

Comment: `WindowsSdkDir not found` <- that's the cause of the problem. Did you test the linked example (yprime) and did it successfully build?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94469-why-do-i-receive-a-fatal-error-error-u1052-file-ntwin32-mak-not-found-when-i-try-to-simulate-my

Comment: Are you really using a beta version? "Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Beta2"